# Duda con condicional de arduino

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Quiero una funcion que espere cierto tiempo hasta que se cumpla la condicional para poder continuar con la otra

por ejemplo quiero que espere a que le llegue tres pulsos con 1 segundo de diferencia cada uno del pin analogico para que continue con la siguiente funcion

esta es el tipo de señal que recive (estadol > 400)

Este es parte del codigo de mi pregunta especificamente donde tengo la duda

Este es uno que con el delay espera los 3 pulsos. Pero la idea de este es que con la funcion espere los 3 pulsos para que sea mas exacto porq con los delay puede fallar porq lo que esta leyendo a veces no envia los pulsos con un tiempo exacto

```
void n3(){
  digitalWrite(llave, HIGH);
  delay(1500);
  if (analogRead(estadol) > 400) {
    delay(4500);
  }
  digitalWrite(llave, LOW);
  delay(1000);
}
```

Y este es el otro se supone que espera hasta que llegue el pulso y comprueba varias veces pero la pregunta es si se puede hacer sin el delay. La idea es, si se puede ejecutar la funcion y que la misma espere a un pulso continuo de 2 segundos para continuar

```
void espera(){
  if (analogRead(led2) > 400) {
    delay(500); // Wait for 100 millisecond(s)
      if (analogRead(led2) > 400) {
        delay(200); // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)
    } else {
      ingresarpro();      
    }
      if (analogRead(led2) > 400) {
        delay(800); // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)
    } else {
      ingresarpro();      
    }
      if (analogRead(led2) > 400) {
        delay(500); // Wait for 500 millisecond(s)
    } else {
      ingresarpro();      
    }
  } else {
    ingresarpro();
  }
}
```

Comment: Coloca tu codigo.

Answer (score 0):

No es recomendable usar `delay` para sincronizar eventos en Arduino. La razón más obvia es que mientras estás en `delay`, no puedes hacer nada más, incluyendo otras tareas periodicas, como muestrear algún sensor o reaccionar a un switch o cualquier otro evento.

El uso de `delay` hace inexacto los cálculos de tiempo, pues no incluye los tiempos gastados en otras partes del programa, incluyendo otros potenciales delay.

La solución recomendada para ejecutar un evento en **N** tiempo más es:

1. Obtener el tiempo actual con `millis()` y conservarlo.
2. En cada pasada de `loop`, calcular cuanto tiempo ha pasado. Si se cumplió el plazo, ejecutar el evento. En caso contrario, no hacer nada.

Es importante calcular los tiempos usando diferencias, o sea `millis() - tiempo > plazo` y no sumas `millis() > tiempo + plazo` por la posibilidad de overflow.

Ahora, cuando son dos o más eventos, necesitas agregar una variable de estado que de diga que evento estás esperando. Todo esto lo puedes poner en una función aparte, para no complicar el `loop`.

En este ejemplo, el Arduino tiene que ejecutar dos eventos (encender, apagar un LED) con tiempos de espera programables antes de cada uno. En tu caso, los eventos serían leer un pin analógico.

Primero declaramos un `enum` que registra todos los estados posibles de la secuencia de operaciones a realizar. También declaramos una variable global que almacena el estado en que se encuentra la secuencia de operaciones:

```
enum estado {inactivo, detenido, esperando1, esperando2};

estado etapa = detenido;
```

El estado `inactivo` significa que no hay que hacer nada. El estado `detenido` es la señal para empezar a operar. Manejando esta variable global puedo iniciar la ejecución de los eventos.

Tenemos está función que se encarga de ejecutar los eventos uno tras otro, y que debe ser llamado periódicamente por `loop`. La función recibe los tiempos de espera antes de encender y antes de apagar el LED de la placa, en milisegundos.

La variable `start` está declarada estática y conserva el tiempo de inicio de la etapa actual, y sirve para calcular cuando termina la etapa y corresponde pasar a la siguiente.

```
void encender(int espera1, int espera2) {
  static unsigned long start = 0;
  
  switch (etapa) {
    case detenido:
      start = millis();
      etapa = esperando1;
      Serial.println("Esperando para encender");
      break;
    case esperando1:
      if ((millis() - start) >= espera1) {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
        start = millis();
        etapa = esperando2;
        Serial.println("Encendido");
        }
       break;
    case esperando2:
      if ((millis() - start) >= espera2) {
        digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        start = 0;
        etapa = inactivo;
        Serial.println("Apagado");
      }
  }
}
```

El `setup` es simple:

```
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.println("Empezando ...");
  delay(3000);
}
```

y el `loop` se limita a llamar a la función `encender` mientras ésta se encuentre fuera del estado `inactiva`. También incluye un `delay`, que simula la carga de otras funciones, e imprime un mensaje cada segundo para chequear los eventos:

```
void loop() {
  Serial.println("loop");
  if (etapa != inactivo) {
    encender(1000, 5000);  
  }  
  delay(1000);
}
```

produce:

```
Empezando ...
loop
Esperando para encender
loop
Encendido
loop
loop
loop
loop
loop
Apagado
loop
loop
```

Comment: Y no habria una forma sin usar esperas. No importa si se detiene todo el flujo del loop. Lo que quiero es que continue cuando cumpla ciertos requisitos como lectura de pulsos externos de lo contrario no